# custom normalizer_fn in tf.feature_column.numeric_column, how to reload the SavedModel file

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

TensorFlow2:  When I use custom normalizer_fn in tf.feature_column.numeric_column, how to save the whole model to TF format and reload from the SavedModel file?

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vincent/Documents/projects/MetaApp/deeplearning/src/test1.py", line 81, in <module>
    loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./saved_models/1')
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 187, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 121, in load
    path, options=options, loader_cls=KerasObjectLoader)
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 633, in load_internal
    ckpt_options)
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 194, in __init__
    super(KerasObjectLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 130, in __init__
    self._load_all()
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 215, in _load_all
    self._layer_nodes = self._load_layers()
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 315, in _load_layers
    layers[node_id] = self._load_layer(proto.user_object, node_id)
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 341, in _load_layer
    obj, setter = self._revive_from_config(proto.identifier, metadata, node_id)
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 359, in _revive_from_config
    self._revive_layer_from_config(metadata, node_id))
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 417, in _revive_layer_from_config
    generic_utils.serialize_keras_class_and_config(class_name, config))
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 175, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 358, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/feature_column/base_feature_layer.py", line 141, in from_config
    config['feature_columns'], custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/serialization.py", line 186, in deserialize_feature_columns
    for c in configs
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/serialization.py", line 186, in <listcomp>
    for c in configs
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/serialization.py", line 138, in deserialize_feature_column
    columns_by_name=columns_by_name)
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py", line 2622, in from_config
    config['normalizer_fn'], custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/Users/vincent/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/serialization.py", line 273, in _deserialize_keras_object
    obj = module_objects.get(object_name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have create a gist demo to show my problem:
https://colab.research.google.com/gist/fuhailin/15cc24100e6de025a98688f4927cebac/untitled418.ipynb

my custom normalizer_fn is:

```
def scale_fn(x):
    x = tf.dtypes.cast(x, tf.float32)
    condition = tf.greater_equal(x, 0)
    x = tf.where(condition, tf.math.log1p(x), x)
    return x
```

When I set

```
age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("age", 
                                           dtype=tf.int64,
                                           normalizer_fn=None)
```

That will work through, so how can I save custom normalizer_fn in tf.feature_column.numeric_column?